# Connect Four winning combinations check works for most cases, but doesn't for certain ones

Tags: c++, debugging, multidimensional-array, stack, 2d-games

So, I basically kept a log of all the test cases I made. Fortunately, most of them work (especially for vertical win check), but sometimes it says there's a winner even when there are not four connected pieces.

(This is what I am doing for a personal project, not a school assignment.)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
const int stSize = 6;
const int width = 7;

class myStack // class for myStack. Each column is a stack.
{
 private:
     int boardArr[width][stSize];
     int inUseA;
     int inUseB;
     int inUseC;
     int inUseD;
     int inUseE;
     int inUseF;
     int inUseG;
     int moveNumber;
     int slotsLeft;
     //char player; 
 public:
 myStack ()
 {
     for(int p = 0; p<width;p++) {
         for(int c = 0; c<stSize;c++){
         boardArr[p][c] = 'O';
         }
     }
     inUseA = -1;
     inUseB = -1;
     inUseC = -1;
     inUseD = -1;
     inUseE = -1;
     inUseF = -1;
     inUseG = -1;
     moveNumber = 0;
     slotsLeft = 42;
 }

 int getstSize() {
     return stSize;
 }

 int getMoveNumber() {
     return moveNumber;
 }

 int getSlotsLeft() {
     return slotsLeft;
 }

void showBoard() {
    printf("  =============================\n");
    printf("1:| %c | %c | %c | %c | %c | %c | %c |\n",boardArr[0][5],boardArr[1][5],boardArr[2][5],boardArr[3][5], boardArr[4][5],boardArr[5][5],boardArr[6][5]);
    printf("2:| %c | %c | %c | %c | %c | %c | %c |\n",boardArr[0][4],boardArr[1][4],boardArr[2][4],boardArr[3][4], boardArr[4][4],boardArr[5][4],boardArr[6][4]);
    printf("3:| %c | %c | %c | %c | %c | %c | %c |\n",boardArr[0][3],boardArr[1][3],boardArr[2][3],boardArr[3][3], boardArr[4][3],boardArr[5][3],boardArr[6][3]);
    printf("4:| %c | %c | %c | %c | %c | %c | %c |\n",boardArr[0][2],boardArr[1][2],boardArr[2][2],boardArr[3][2], boardArr[4][2],boardArr[5][2],boardArr[6][2]);
    printf("5:| %c | %c | %c | %c | %c | %c | %c |\n",boardArr[0][1],boardArr[1][1],boardArr[2][1],boardArr[3][1], boardArr[4][1],boardArr[5][1],boardArr[6][1]);
    printf("6:| %c | %c | %c | %c | %c | %c | %c |\n",boardArr[0][0],boardArr[1][0],boardArr[2][0],boardArr[3][0], boardArr[4][0],boardArr[5][0],boardArr[6][0]);
    printf("  =============================\n"); // FORMAT: ([WIDTH][HEIGHT])
    printf("    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   \n");
    }

void pushA() {
    char data;
    if (moveNumber % 2 != 0) {
        data = '@';
    }
    else {
        data = '#';
    }
 if (inUseA == stSize-1) {
     printf("Error. Stack's full.\n");
     return;
 }
 else {
     inUseA = inUseA +1;
     boardArr[0][inUseA] = data;
     slotsLeft--;
     moveNumber++;
 }

}
void pushB() {
    char data;
    if (moveNumber % 2 != 0) {
        data = '@';
    }
    else {
        data = '#';
    }
    if (inUseB == stSize-1) {
        printf("Error. Stack's full.\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        inUseB = inUseB +1;
        boardArr[1][inUseB] = data;
        slotsLeft--;
        moveNumber++;
    }
   }
void pushC() {
    char data;
    if (moveNumber % 2 != 0) {
        data = '@';
    }
    else {
        data = '#';
    }
    if (inUseC == stSize-1) {
        printf("Error. Stack's full.\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        inUseC = inUseC +1;
        boardArr[2][inUseC] = data;
        slotsLeft--;
        moveNumber++;
    }
}
void pushD() {
    char data;
    if (moveNumber % 2 != 0) {
        data = '@';
    }
    else {
        data = '#';
    }
    if (inUseD == stSize-1) {
        printf("Error. Stack's full.\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        inUseD = inUseD +1;
        boardArr[3][inUseD] = data;
        slotsLeft--;
        moveNumber++;
    }
}

void pushE() {
    char data;
    if (moveNumber % 2 != 0) {
        data = '@';
    }
    else {
        data = '#';
    }
    if (inUseE == stSize-1) {
        printf("Error. Stack's full.\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        inUseE = inUseE +1;
        boardArr[4][inUseE] = data;
        slotsLeft--;
        moveNumber++;
    }
}

void pushF() {
    char data;
    if (moveNumber % 2 != 0) {
        data = '@';
    }
    else {
        data = '#';
    }
    if (inUseF == stSize-1) {
        printf("Error. Stack's full.\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        inUseF = inUseF +1;
        boardArr[5][inUseF] = data;
        slotsLeft--;
        moveNumber++;
    }
}

void pushG() {
    char data;
    if (moveNumber % 2 != 0) {
        data = '@';
    }
    else {
        data = '#';
    }
    if (inUseG == stSize-1) {
        printf("Error. Stack's full.\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        inUseG = inUseG +1;
        boardArr[6][inUseG] = data;
        slotsLeft--;
        moveNumber++;
    }
}

int HorizontalWin() {
    int horizCounter1 = 0;
    int horizCounter2 = 0;

    for(int n = 0; n<stSize;n++) {
        for(int m = 0; m<width;m++) {
            if(boardArr[n][m] == '@') {
                horizCounter1++;
                horizCounter2 = 0;
            }
            else if(boardArr[n][m] == '#') {
                horizCounter2++;
                horizCounter1 = 0;
            }
        }
        if(horizCounter1 == 5 || horizCounter2 == 5) {
            printf("Winner!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int VerticalWin () {
    int vertCounter1 = 0;
    int vertCounter2 = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x<width;x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y<stSize;y++) {
            if(boardArr[x][y] == '@') {
                vertCounter1++;
        vertCounter2 = 0;
            }
            else if(boardArr[x][y] == '#') {
                vertCounter2++;
        vertCounter1 = 0;
            }
        }
        if(vertCounter1 == 4 || vertCounter2 == 4) {
            printf("Winner!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int diagonalWin() { // Don't mind this, i haven't started making this yet
    return 0;
}

void processCommandLoop (FILE* inFile)
{
 char  buffer[300];
 char* input;

 input = fgets ( buffer, 300, inFile );   // get a line of input

 // loop until all lines are read from the input
 while (input != NULL)
 {
   // process each line of input using the strtok functions 
   char* command;
   command = strtok (input , " \n\t");

   printf ("*%s*\n", command);

   if ( command == NULL ) {
     printf ("Blank Line\n"); 
   }

   else if ( strcmp (command, "q") == 0){ 
     exit(1); 
   }

   else if ( strcmp (command, "?") == 0){ 
     showCommands();
   }

   else if ( strcmp (command, "a") == 0){ 
     pushA();
     showBoard();
     if (VerticalWin() == 1 || HorizontalWin() == 1) {
         break;
     }
   }
   else if ( strcmp (command, "b") == 0){ 
     pushB();
     showBoard();
     if (VerticalWin() == 1 || HorizontalWin() == 1) {
         break;
     }
   }
   else if ( strcmp (command, "c") == 0){ 
     pushC();
     showBoard();
     if (VerticalWin() == 1|| HorizontalWin() == 1) {
         break;
     }
   }
   else if ( strcmp (command, "d") == 0){ 
     pushD();
     showBoard();
     if (VerticalWin() == 1|| HorizontalWin() == 1) {
         break;
     }
   }
   else if ( strcmp (command, "e") == 0){ 
     pushE();
     showBoard();
     if (VerticalWin() == 1|| HorizontalWin() == 1) {
         break;
     }
   }
   else if ( strcmp (command, "f") == 0){ 
     pushF();
     showBoard();
     if (VerticalWin() == 1|| HorizontalWin() == 1) {
         break;
     }
   }
   else if ( strcmp (command, "g") == 0){ 
     pushG();
     showBoard();
     if (VerticalWin() == 1|| HorizontalWin() == 1) {
         break;
     }
   }
   else {
     printf ("Invalid input: %s\n", command);
   }
   input = fgets ( buffer, 300, inFile );   // get the next line of input

 }
}


void showCommands()
{
  printf ("The commands for this game:\n");
  printf("At any point, you may quit the game by entering 'q'");
  printf ("  q \n");
  printf ("  ? \n");
  printf ("  a \n");
  printf ("  b  \n");
  printf ("  c \n");
  printf ("  d \n");
  printf ("  e \n");
  printf ("  f \n");
  printf ("  g \n");
  printf("Options a-g mean that you can push a piece into the indicated stack\n");
}

};


 int main()
 {
   FILE* inFile = stdin;

   myStack test;
   test.showCommands();
   test.showBoard();
   test.processCommandLoop(inFile);
   printf("Quitting..\n");
   return 1;
 }
```

So, yes, I know I didn't write the program that efficiently (especially given that I have so many push functions xD, but my main concern is my algorithm for determining who won. My vertical case works for the most part, but my horizontal one hardly does.

To know what I mean, please take a look at my test cases:

```
  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| # | O | O | O | O | O | O |
3:| # | @ | O | O | O | O | O |
4:| # | @ | O | O | O | O | O |
5:| # | @ | O | O | O | O | O |
6:| @ | # | O | O | O | O | O |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!
--
  =============================
1:| @ | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| @ | O | O | O | O | O | O |
3:| @ | O | O | O | O | O | O |
4:| @ | @ | # | O | O | O | O |
5:| # | # | # | O | O | O | O |
6:| @ | # | # | O | O | O | O |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!
  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
3:| # | O | O | O | O | O | O |
4:| # | O | O | O | O | O | O |
5:| # | O | @ | O | O | O | O |
6:| # | @ | @ | O | O | O | O |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!
---------------------------------A

  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
3:| O | @ | O | O | O | O | O |
4:| O | @ | O | O | O | O | O |
5:| # | @ | # | O | O | O | O |
6:| # | @ | # | O | O | O | O |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G

Winner!
  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | # | O | O | O | O | O |
3:| O | # | O | O | O | O | O |
4:| @ | # | O | O | O | O | O |
5:| @ | # | O | O | O | O | O |
6:| # | @ | @ | O | O | O | O |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!
  =============================
1:| @ | # | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| @ | # | O | O | O | O | O |
3:| @ | # | O | O | O | O | O |
4:| # | # | @ | O | O | O | O |
5:| # | @ | @ | O | O | O | O |
6:| # | @ | # | O | O | O | O |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
```

Winner!
    ------------------------------------B

```
  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
3:| O | O | @ | O | O | O | O |
4:| O | O | @ | O | O | O | O |
5:| O | O | @ | O | # | O | O |
6:| # | O | @ | O | # | O | # |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!
  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | # | O | O | O | O |
3:| O | O | # | O | O | O | O |
4:| O | O | # | O | O | O | O |
5:| @ | O | # | @ | O | O | O |
6:| @ | O | @ | # | O | O | O |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!

  =============================
1:| O | O | @ | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | @ | O | O | O | O |
3:| O | O | @ | # | O | O | O |
4:| O | O | @ | # | O | O | O |
5:| O | O | # | # | O | O | O |
6:| O | O | # | @ | O | O | O |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G

Winner!
  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
3:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
4:| O | O | @ | O | O | O | O |
5:| # | O | @ | O | O | O | O |
6:| # | O | @ | @ | O | # | # |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!^^ shouldnt be the case.. this implies that even adjacent pieces are counted for win status.

------------------------------------C
  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
3:| O | O | O | # | O | O | O |
4:| O | O | @ | # | O | O | O |
5:| O | O | @ | # | O | O | O |
6:| O | O | @ | # | O | O | O |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!
  =============================
1:| O | O | O | @ | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | @ | O | O | O |
3:| O | O | O | @ | O | O | O |
4:| O | O | O | @ | O | O | O |
5:| # | O | @ | # | O | O | O |
6:| # | # | @ | # | O | O | # |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!
  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | @ | O | O | O |
3:| O | O | O | @ | O | O | O |
4:| # | O | O | @ | O | O | O |
5:| # | O | O | @ | O | O | O |
6:| # | O | O | # | O | O | O |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!
------------------------------------D

  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
3:| O | O | O | O | # | O | O |
4:| O | O | O | O | # | O | O |
5:| @ | O | O | O | # | O | O |
6:| @ | O | O | O | # | O | @ |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!
  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | O | @ | O | O |
3:| O | O | O | O | @ | O | O |
4:| # | O | O | O | @ | O | O |
5:| # | O | O | O | @ | O | O |
6:| # | O | O | O | # | O | O |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!

  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | @ | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | O | @ | O | O |
3:| O | O | O | O | @ | O | O |
4:| O | O | O | O | @ | O | O |
5:| # | O | O | # | # | O | O |
6:| @ | # | O | @ | # | O | # |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!
------------------------------------E

  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
3:| O | O | O | O | O | # | O |
4:| O | O | O | O | O | # | O |
5:| @ | O | O | O | O | # | O |
6:| @ | @ | O | O | O | # | O |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!

  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | O | O | @ | O |
3:| O | O | O | O | O | @ | O |
4:| O | O | O | O | O | @ | O |
5:| # | O | O | O | O | @ | O |
6:| # | # | O | O | O | # | O |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!


  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | @ | O |
2:| O | O | O | O | O | @ | O |
3:| O | O | O | O | O | @ | O |
4:| O | O | O | O | O | @ | O |
5:| O | O | O | O | O | # | O |
6:| @ | # | # | # | O | # | O |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!

------------------------------------F
  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
3:| O | O | O | O | O | O | # |
4:| O | O | O | O | O | O | # |
5:| @ | O | O | O | O | O | # |
6:| @ | O | @ | O | O | O | # |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!
  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | @ |
2:| O | O | O | O | O | O | @ |
3:| O | O | O | O | O | O | @ |
4:| # | O | # | O | O | O | @ |
5:| @ | O | # | O | O | O | # |
6:| @ | # | @ | O | # | O | # |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!

  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | O | O | O | # |
3:| O | O | O | O | O | O | # |
4:| @ | O | O | O | O | O | # |
5:| @ | O | O | O | @ | O | # |
6:| # | @ | O | O | # | O | @ |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!

>>>pay special attention to this error
  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
3:| O | O | O | O | O | O | @ |
4:| # | O | O | O | O | O | @ |
5:| # | O | O | O | O | O | @ |
6:| # | O | # | @ | O | O | # |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner! < shouldnt be the case
------------------------------------G

horizontal error:
  =============================
1:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
2:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
3:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
4:| O | O | O | O | O | O | O |
5:| O | O | O | O | @ | O | O |
6:| # | # | # | O | @ | O | O |
  =============================
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Winner!< shouldnt be the case
```

As you can see, most of the vertical cases did work, but I see a few errors here and there.

Also, my horizontal check is HARDLY working.

So, fellow CS people, where do you think I need to tweak the algorithm? 
The reason why I put verticalCounter1=0 when vertcounter2 is incremented is that if a blue piece is top of a red piece on column X, then that would affect the counter of the red piece so that red pieces would have to amount to 4 again.

I tried debugging this manually with all those cases, but I am not sure how to use the GDB for cases like this. I know how to use it for segmentation faults and memory leaks, but I am new to CPP, so I apologize if I goofed up here. I tried my best.

Comment: Bumping this post..

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems:

1. You aren't resetting the counters to 0 when you hit a blank space. Both counters should reset if you encounter a position with nothing in it. This doesn't cause a problem for the vertical case because there aren't blank spaces between occupied spaces, but it is a problem for the other win types
2. You aren't reseting the counter when you move to a new row/column/diagonal. For example, in the HorizontalWin, When you finish checking the first row, you should reset the counter before you move on to the second row, because all four pieces need to be in the same row.